# Is free energy perturbation theory based on semi-classical approximation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

From
https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Workshop/Urbana_2010A/lectures/TCBG-2010.pdf
page 14, the partition function is formulated in terms of integral over $d\mathbf{x} d\mathbf{p}_x$
$$
Q = \frac{1}{h^{3N} N!} \int \int \exp [ -\beta \mathcal{H}(\mathbf{x} , \mathbf{p}_x) d\mathbf{x} d\mathbf{p}_x
$$
My question is, integral over position and momentum is semi classical to me, since in quantum mechanics, position and momentum can not be determined exactly at the same time and the presence of $h^{3N}$ seems to be resemble the uncertainty principle.

Then, is free energy perturbation theory based on semi-classical approximation? If so, how good it is?

Comment: You should recognise this from a standard introduction to statistical thermodynamics. This is a rather good approximation as long as Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics is tolerable.